# Specify temporary directory in .jnlp

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I'm accessing a java applet that is running on a website (which i can't access/modify the content) you can find the applet here : xxx

I want to be able to specify a temporary folder at start because if i have two instances of that applet running they will overlap the files, they store in the same temporary folder.

I wonder if it's every possible to tell the applet to write in a specified temporary folder.

Tried to add property :

```
<property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="/tmp/user1" />
```

But doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can download all those `jar` files and then just run it via `java -jar` specifying proper class path, main class, memory settings, temporary folder, etc. Consult original `jnlp` file for more details.

Not sure if it will work, but you can give it a try.

Comment: To close the thread; no it's not possible. The application actually 'hard coded' the temporary folder. But thx anyway.